# Momentjs change timezone without affecting time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to set the timezone for a date in moment.js without changing the time value.

I get a date in utc:

```
const date = "2022-01-18T00:00:00.000Z";
```

And Im doing the next with moment-timezone

```
moment(date).tz("America/Bogota", true).format();
```

It is supposed to change the timezone without affecting the time but im getting:

> 2022-01-17T19:00:00-05:00

And what I expect:

> 2022-01-18T00:00:00-05:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this way:

```
moment.utc(date).tz("America/Bogota", true).format();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest perhaps using the moment.tz constructor with a format string. This way, we'll parse the input date as a local time.

```js
const date = "2022-01-18T00:00:00.000Z";

console.log(moment.tz(date, "YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:sss.SSS", "America/Bogota").format());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-1970-2030.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't working, If I run the code snippet Im getting: `2022-01-17T19:00:00-05:00` and not the expected `2022-01-18T00:00:00-05:00`

Comment: Apologies, I have updated to an improved solution.

Comment: This is indeed a correct solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though `.format` may be converting the date into local time.
The results I get with various time zones in moment

[image: results]

The date you provided converted from UTC to my local time
[image: utc converted]

With my local `moment()`
[image: local time]